# kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail not pulling images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Most of my contacts image are pulled in from image and when I do:

```
NSData *contactImageData = (__bridge NSData*) ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person,
                                                                                  kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:contactImageData];
```

the img here is nil. How can I get the image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before fetching image please check if the address does have image property using the below line.

```
if(ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
    //Code to fetch image
}
```